# How do I gracefully close a socket with a persistent HTTP connection?

Tags: python, http, sockets, networking, network-programming

I'm writing a very simple client in Python that fetches an HTML page from the WWW. This is the code I've come up with so far:

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("www.mywebsite.com", 80))
sock.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:www.mywebsite.com\r\n\r\n")

while True:
    chunk = sock.recv(1024) # (1)
    if len(chunk) == 0:
        break
    print(chunk)

sock.close()
```

The problem is: being an HTTP/1.1 connection persistent by default, the code gets stuck in `# (1)` waiting for more data from the server once the transmission is over.

I know I can solve this by a) adding the `Connection: close` request header, or by b) setting a timeout to the socket. A non-blocking socket here would not help, as the `select()` syscall would still hang (unless I set a timeout on it, but that's just another form of case b)).

So is there another way to do it, while keeping the connection persistent?

Comment: You are not parsing the response at all to know when it actually ends. See [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) and [RFC 7230 Section 3.3.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3). Then you can do whatever you want between when the response ends and when you want to send a new request on the same connection. Also, you need to check for a `Connection: close` header, or a `Keep-Alive` header indicating a timeout for the connection and/or a maximum number of requests allowed per connection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau so parsing the response headers, specifically the `Content-Length` one seems the way to go.

Comment: parsing involves more than just the headers. Please read the RFCs I mentioned, there is much more than just handling `Content-Length`. See my [past answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+http+pseudo) on this subject

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said in the comments, there's a lot to consider if you're trying to write an all-singing, all-dancing HTTP processor. However, if you're just practising with sockets then consider this.

Let's assume that you know how the response will end. For example, if we do essentially what you're doing in your code to the main Google page, we **know** that the response will end with '\r\n\r\n'. So, what we can do is just read 1 byte at a time and look out for that terminating sequence.

This code will **NOT** give you the full Google main page because, as you will see, the response is chunked - and that's a whole new ball game.

Having said all of that, you may find this instructive:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    sock.connect(('www.google.com', 80))
    sock.send(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:www.google.com\r\n\r\n')
    end = [b'\r', b'\n', b'\r', b'\n']
    d = []
    while d[-len(end):] != end:
        d.append(sock.recv(1))
    print(''.join(b.decode() for b in d))
finally:
    sock.close()
```